# How to capture C++ output to a Bash variable?

Tags: c++, bash

I'd like to compile and run a C++ program via Bash and then capture the output produced by `cout` (which will be a int) to a variable in the Bash script.

I'm currently able to direct the output to a text file like so:

`./prog >> output.txt`

My research has led me to this, which appears to be creating an empty string:

`output=$(./prog) | bc -l`

In case it's relevant, I'm trying to capture this value so that I can average the output of my program over multiple executions. Here's my entire script as it currently stands:

```
count=1
while [ $count -le 8192 ]
do
    sum=0
    arraysize=$(( $count * 1024 ))
    g++-7 prog.cpp -DGLOBAL=${arraysize} -DLOCAL=32 -o prog -lm -fopenmp -framework OpenCL
    for try in {0..9}
    do
        output=$(./prog) | bc -l
        echo ${output} # this line appears to print an empty string
        sum=$(( (sum + output) ))
    done
    echo ${sum / 10}
    count=$(( $count * 2 ))
done
```

I know that there are likely other errors in the script above, but the one that's currently hanging me up is just capturing the value produced by the program.

Comment: What does the output look like?

Comment: Ten blank lines.

Comment: I'm meaning from `./prog >> output.txt`...

Comment: Just integers separated by carriage returns: 3023344433, etc.

Comment: Why are you piping to `bc`? Maybe try to move that into the parenthesis, if you actually want to capture the output `bc` gives for the output of your program.

Comment: My understanding was that this was necessary to force Bash to treat the input as a number.

Comment: @AlexJohnson Anything that looks like a number will be treated as a number. You can also use `typeset -i output` to declare the variable to hold an integer.

Comment: But if it's multiple numbers on different lines, it won't be treated as a single number. Perhaps you should be putting them into an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's more than one way, but one is to use the backtick character:

```
VAR=`./prog`
```

Comment: [Why is $(...) preferred over \`...\` (backticks)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082)

Comment: This (and $(...), for the record) appear to have solved my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what could help:

```
var=$(./prog)
```